stdin.readlinesync() how it can take int

import 'dart:io';
void main (){
print("type your name: ");
var name = stdin.readLineSync();
print("type your age: ");
var age  = stdin.readLineSync();
var age2 = int.parse(age);
var age3 = (100-age2);
print("you will be 100 years old after: $age3");
}


still show me same error the argument type string can't be assigned to the parameter type num
how it can solve??
I want take int input from the user

You might also wish to read https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Check the error message. My bet is it says "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.", and not anything about num.
